# Create price rules in WCS using OOB commands

Tags: wcs

Currently I have a pricerule that has only one action element to fetch a price from pricelist.

[image: simple pricerule]

In order to achieve this pricerule I'm adding entries into required tables like

- PRICERULE,
- PRELEMENT,
- PRELEMENTATTR
- and other tables.

Now I need to add more conditions and branches to this pricerule in order to fit for the requirements(something like this).

[image: complex pricerule]

But I found forming this pricerule by inserting entries directly into tables (as I did for simple pricerule) is quite complex. Because after forming the pricerule it has to be updated on weekly basis. Updates will be like changing the markup/markdown percentage or changing the start and end date of this markup etc.

**So my question is:**
Instead of directly updating the tables, is there any IBM WCS OOB functionality to achieve this?

Comment: I incorporated the two images and improved the formatting of the question.

Comment: @zx485 Thanks for the edit :)